# Spring test NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring

I know there are a lot of similar questions but none of them seem to help me or gets me an understanding of the problem. I am also new to spring so this is why i am probably stuck with such a beginner problem.

The problem:

I have a (currently very basic) spring application which runs fine. But the test wont because i run into a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` and i cannot figure out why. Should my tests not find the same beans my application normally does? I thought the annotations are taking care of that?

My application is very basic: one controller, one method and one service one method. No dependencies, nothing. The most basic setup from https://start.spring.io/. Then i have one controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/location")
public class LocationController
{
    @Autowired
    LocationService locationService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/get/{lat}/{lon}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public LocationData getLocationInfo(@PathVariable Double lat, @PathVariable Double lon) throws Exception {
        return locationService.getByCoordinates(lat, lon);
    }
}
```

and for the service my interface (just plain `public interface LocationService`) and implementation:

```
@Service
public class LocationServiceImpl implements LocationService {
    public LocationData getByCoordinates(Double lat, Double lon) {
        return new LocationData(lat, lon, "Test");
    }
}
```

I know i could maybe inject a mocked service to make it work, or use a test configuration and have some bean setup defined there. But should it not work out of the box? Why is it not finding my service?

EDIT:

And of course the test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(LocationController.class)
public class LocationControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void whenGetLocation_thenReturnJsonArray() throws Exception {
        String resp = mvc.perform(get("/location/get/1.00/2.00"))
           .andExpect(status().isOk())
           .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using `@WebMvcTest` which is only for testing web related stuff it will also construct a minimal application with only the web related beans NOT services, repos, daos, datasources etc. etc. So in this case you need a `@MockBean` for the service. If you want a full integration test use `@SpringBootTest` instead of `@WebMvcTest` which will launch the full application.

Comment: Actually i tried that and it seemed to result in the same error. I rechecked and actually this time it was `MockMvc` that was not found and could simply be configured via `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`. Thank you. You happen to know if i could for now import my actual service without mocking and still use `WebMvcTest`? So far i just quickly tried `@Import` and a Bean in the test configuration without luck. Thank you anyway.

Comment: You can provide additional configuration to be included, but if you include your service, you need the dependencies of the service as well. Etc. etc. you will start going down a rabbit hole.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. I know what you mean, i will take a look into it. I was going to mock it anyway at some point, but currently it basically is a dependencyless mock and i'd like to include tests even in early commits, probably just mock it yet after all. If you want to post you as an answer i would accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely missing a @ContextConfiguration in your test. The Spring unit test runner doesn't know there is a LocationServiceImpl.